# Weird Discrepencies in Layer Shapes when Calling Model

Tags: python, tensorflow, autoencoder

I am trying to use the output of a variational autoencoder to aid in classifying images. I have pre-trainned the autoencoder and am now trying to load the weights in another script to use the weights of the encoder model for prediction. I am having a weird error when calling the encoder that I cannot make sense of. When I try to call the encoder on a sample, I am told that the shapes are incompatible:
`ValueError: Input 0 of layer dense is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 1048576 but received input with shape (256, 8192)`. This is confusing because I have pre-trained the model fine and have instantiated the model like I did before (I copy/pasted the code). I have based my model on this [YouTube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8wrLjnQ7EWQ).

I will also paste in my code:

```
    ##########      Library Imports         ##########
import os, sys
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, Input, Flatten, Dense, Lambda, Reshape, Conv2DTranspose
import keras
import keras.backend as K
from keras.models import Model
from PIL import Image

print(tf.version.VERSION)

img_height = 256 #chosen
img_width = 256
num_channels = 1 #grayscale

input_shape = (img_height, img_width, num_channels)

##########      Load VAE Weights        ##########
vae_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'vae_training')
checkpoint_path = os.path.join(vae_path, 'cp.ckpt')

print('vae_path listdir\n', os.listdir(vae_path))

#load patches
#patch_locs = sys.argv[1] #path to the patch folders
patch_locs = r'C:\Users\Daniel\Documents\GitHub\endo_git_v2\patches\single_wsi_for_local_parent'

patch_folders = os.listdir(patch_locs)
print(patch_folders)

##########      INSTANTIATE MODEL AND LOAD WEIGHTS      ##########

#REPARAMETERIZATION TRICK
# Define sampling function to sample from the distribution
# Reparameterize sample based on the process defined by Gunderson and Huang
# into the shape of: mu + sigma squared x eps
#This is to allow gradient descent to allow for gradient estimation accurately. 
def sample_z(args):
  z_mu, z_sigma = args
  z_mu = tf.cast(z_mu, dtype=tf.float32)
  z_sigma = tf.cast(z_sigma, dtype=tf.float32)
  eps = K.random_normal(shape=(K.shape(z_mu)[0], K.int_shape(z_mu)[1]))
  out = z_mu + K.exp(z_sigma / 2) * eps
  return out

#Define custom loss
#VAE is trained using two loss functions reconstruction loss and KL divergence
#Let us add a class to define a custom layer with loss
class CustomLayer(keras.layers.Layer):

    def vae_loss(self, x, z_decoded):
        x = K.flatten(x)
        z_decoded = K.flatten(z_decoded)
        
        # Reconstruction loss (as we used sigmoid activation we can use binarycrossentropy)
        recon_loss = keras.metrics.binary_crossentropy(x, z_decoded)
        recon_loss = tf.cast(recon_loss, dtype=tf.float32)
        
        # KL divergence
        kl_loss = -5e-4 * K.mean(1 + z_sigma - K.square(z_mu) - K.exp(z_sigma), axis=-1)
        kl_loss = tf.cast(kl_loss, dtype=tf.float32)
        return K.mean(recon_loss + kl_loss)

    # add custom loss to the class
    def call(self, inputs):
        x = inputs[0]
        z_decoded = inputs[1]
        loss = self.vae_loss(x, z_decoded)
        self.add_loss(loss, inputs=inputs)
        return x

# # ================= #############
# # Encoder
#Let us define 4 conv2D, flatten and then dense
# # ================= ############

latent_dim = 256 # Number of latent dim parameters

input_img = Input(shape=input_shape, name='encoder_input')
print(input_img.shape)
x = Conv2D(32, 3, padding='same', activation='relu')(input_img)
print(x.shape)
x = Conv2D(64, 3, padding='same', activation='relu',strides=(2, 2))(x)
print(x.shape)
x = Conv2D(64, 3, padding='same', activation='relu')(x)
print(x.shape)
x = Conv2D(64, 3, padding='same', activation='relu')(x)
print(x.shape)

conv_shape = K.int_shape(x) #Shape of conv to be provided to decoder (taken after all the conv layers)
print(conv_shape)
#Flatten
x = Flatten()(x)
print(x.shape)
x = Dense(32, activation='relu')(x)
print(x.shape)

# Two outputs, for latent mean and log variance (std. dev.)
#Use these to sample random variables in latent space to which inputs are mapped. 
z_mu = Dense(latent_dim, name='latent_mu')(x)   #Mean values of encoded input
z_sigma = Dense(latent_dim, name='latent_sigma')(x)  #Std dev. (variance) of encoded 

z_mu = tf.cast(z_mu, dtype=tf.float32)
z_sigma = tf.cast(z_sigma, dtype=tf.float32)
print('z_mu.dtype:', z_mu.dtype)
print('z_sigma.dtype:', z_sigma.dtype)

# sample vector from the latent distribution
# z is the labda custom layer we are adding for gradient descent calculations
  # using mu and variance (sigma)
z = Lambda(sample_z, output_shape=(latent_dim, ), name='z')([z_mu, z_sigma])
print('z.dtype:', z.dtype)

#Z (lambda layer) will be the last layer in the encoder.
# Define and summarize encoder model.
encoder = Model(input_img, [z_mu, z_sigma, z], name='encoder')
print(encoder.summary())

# ================= ###########
# Decoder
#
# ================= #################

# decoder takes the latent vector as input
decoder_input = Input(shape=(latent_dim, ), name='decoder_input')

# Need to start with a shape that can be remapped to original image shape as
#we want our final utput to be same shape original input.
#So, add dense layer with dimensions that can be reshaped to desired output shape
x = Dense(conv_shape[1]*conv_shape[2]*conv_shape[3], activation='relu')(decoder_input)
# reshape to the shape of last conv. layer in the encoder, so we can 
x = Reshape((conv_shape[1], conv_shape[2], conv_shape[3]))(x)
# upscale (conv2D transpose) back to original shape
# use Conv2DTranspose to reverse the conv layers defined in the encoder
x = Conv2DTranspose(32, 3, padding='same', activation='relu',strides=(2, 2))(x)
#Can add more conv2DTranspose layers, if desired. 
#Using sigmoid activation
x = Conv2DTranspose(num_channels, 3, padding='same', activation='sigmoid', name='decoder_output')(x)

# Define and summarize decoder model
decoder = Model(decoder_input, x, name='decoder')
decoder.summary()

# apply the decoder to the latent sample 
z_decoded = decoder(z)

# apply the custom loss to the input images and the decoded latent distribution sample
y = CustomLayer()([input_img, z_decoded])
# y is basically the original image after encoding input img to mu, sigma, z
# and decoding sampled z values.
#This will be used as output for vae

vae = Model(input_img, y, name='vae')

# Compile VAE
vae.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=None, experimental_run_tf_function=False)
vae.summary()

model_weights_dir = r'C:\Users\Daniel\Documents\GitHub\endo_git_v2\vae_training'
checkpoint_path = os.path.join(model_weights_dir, 'cp.ckpt')

print(os.listdir(model_weights_dir))

#vae.load_weights(checkpoint_path)

##################################################################

##########      Open all WSI, then Open all Patches         ##########

#for wsi in patch_folders: #loops through all the wsi folders
wsi = patch_folders[0]
#start of wsi loop
print('wsi:', wsi)
current_wsi_directory = os.path.join(patch_locs, wsi) #take the current wsi
print('current_wsi_directory:', current_wsi_directory)
patches = os.listdir(current_wsi_directory)

latent_shape = (203, 147, 256)
latent_wsi = np.zeros(latent_shape) #initialized placeholders for latent representations

row = 0
col = 0
for i in range(1):#len(patches)): #should be 29841 every time
    #load patch as numpy array
    patch_path = os.path.join(current_wsi_directory, '{}_{}.jpeg'.format(wsi, i)) #numerical order not alphabetical
    print('patch_path:', patch_path)
    image = Image.open(patch_path)
    data = np.asarray(image)
    #emulate rescale of 1/.255
    data = data / 255.
    data = np.expand_dims(data, axis=-1)
    print('data.shape:', data.shape)
    
    encoder(data, training=False)
```

Any help or tips are very much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue. Long story short that I'm an idiot. I was passing in a numpy array that was (256,256,1) in size (note that the batch dimension was missing). Reshaping to (1, 256, 256, 1) solved my issue (note that the first 1 is the batch dimension)